# can i use the 2D code in unity into my 3D project?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to ask if I can use 2D code for my 3D project? because I'm planning to create a power-ups that the character will gonna be invulnerable for all the monster in a seconds

Comment: Honestly it depends on what the code is doing, you will get better results if you show some kind of example of what you are moving from a 2d into a 3d game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I think you can. Let's say for example you have some method:

```
    private static void PowerUp(List<Monster> monsters)
    {
       // do smth like: 
       foreach(var m in monsters)
       {
          m.Invulnerable(); 
       {
    }
```

In that case, it's totally fine reuse your code but if it's something 3D specific you may not be able to reuse it. Good luck with your project.